# Function with data types

Tags: haskell

I have this data in my code

```
data Client = aClient {name::String,alcohol::Int,friends::[Client]} deriving (Show)
```

I'm trying to make a function that depends on the amount of hours that a client rest, it increase the alcohol resistance.

```
letgo :: Client -> Integer -> Client
letgo (aClient _ alcohol _) hours
```

I need to know how to update that alcohol field within my data depending on the condition.

Comment: start with getting your first line to compile: `data Client = aClient {name::String,alcohol::Int,friends::[Client]} deriving (Show) `

Comment: That won't compile either, ja. The data constructor has to start with a capital letter.

Comment: That's right; that was a tip, not the answer.

Comment: You won't really be "updating" the alcohol field, as you would in an imperative language. Rather, you'll be constructing a new `Client` with the appropriate value in the alcohol field. Would you know how to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```haskell
data Client = Client {name::String,alcohol::Int,friends::[Client]} deriving (Show)

letgo :: Client -> Integer -> Client
letgo client@(Client name alcohol friends) hours
  | sufficientRest hours = Client name (increaseResistance alcohol) friends
  | otherwise = client

sufficientRest     :: Integer -> Bool
increaseResistance :: Int -> Int
```